# Why does Apple recommend defining enumeration types as NSInteger?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Apple's [Adopting Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW6) document, it is specified that:

> The type for enumerations should be NSInteger.

In addition, for the `NS_OPTION` macro, they say:

> However, the type for options should usually be NSUInteger.

Most of the time the enumeration values I use are never negative, therefore I define them as `NSUInteger` instead.

What's the rationale behind this decision?

Answer (score 0):

Someone at Apple knew about this new language named "Swift". Swift is *very* strict with types, so having a mixture of signed and unsigned values is very inconvenient. Therefore, you should use NSInteger even if you know that values are never negative.

Comment: I see no issue with mixing signed and unsigned values, since you're explicitly defining the underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration is not guaranteed to have only positive values.
In some cases `-1` may be used to mark error.

[Here Apple covers this topic in detail](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html)

Comment: Enumeration of specific type can guaranteed to have only positive values (because thats it defined)

Comment: This is incorrect, as by using `NS_ENUM` you specifically define the underlying representation of the enum. Actually, in the document you supplied they give a demo of how to define an enum which is `NSUInteger` backed (without the `NS_ENUM` macro - they specify it manually).

Comment: and if you use just an old fashioned enum instead?

Comment: When not using the `NS_ENUM` macro, you're letting the compiler infer the type for you, which is not 64-bit portable, as said in the link you gave: `The compiler looks at this declaration and, finding a negative value assigned to one of the member constants, declares the underlying type of the enumeration int. If the range of values for the members does not fit into an int or unsigned int, then the base type silently becomes 64-bit (long).`